# transferring data from table to another with column's different format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table contains a column named Admission_Date but the type of this column is VARCHAR

I want to convert this column to the type (Date or Datetime) but couldn't do that because I need to drop the table and create it again.

So I would like to move this column to another table but the new column's type will be Date or Date time. I tried this:

```
insert into TableName (columnName)

select top 10 cast(columnName AS date) from TableName 
order by TableName
```

It doesn't work; what should I do about this?

Comment: Why it doesn't work? what error you got?. How the `ColumnName` data will look like??

Comment: You can't fit `DATETIME` data into `DATE` or the other way around. You need to have the same datatype on both the column you select from and the one you're trying to insert into.

Comment: The table names and columns in you example makes no sense. Could you rewrite it to make it more obvious what you think is the source and the destination?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - No you can directly insert `date` into a `datetime` column and you can convert `datetime` to `date` and it can be inserted into `Date` column

Comment: @NoDisplayName Yes, conversion will work, but I didn't say that it wouldn't.

Comment: you have store the date values in varchar column so what is its format? if it is in a format which is recognized by sql server then you can directly alter that column like : `create table #table (columnname varchar(30))
insert into #table
values
('2014-12-17'),
('12-17-2014'),
('17-Dec-2014')

alter table #table alter column columnname date

select * from #table`

Answer (score 0):

```
 create table adminsion (Admission_Date varchar(20))
 insert into adminsion values('12/23/2012')

 create table adminsion_new (Admission_Date_new  datetime)



 insert into adminsion_new 
 select cast(Admission_Date as datetime)  from adminsion
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.